# Where does the superconducting density of states come from?

Tags: solid-state-physics, superconductivity, density-of-states

I'm going through Tinkham (2nd edition) and in section 3.7.1 he makes a claim which seems quite weird:

[image]

$N_n(\xi)$ is the Normal density of states (normal mode), so how would it be that the density of states in the superconducting regime is modelled by the density of states in the normal regime.

Comment: Conservation of number: number of quasiparticles is simply the same as the number of electrons?

Comment: But $N_s(E)$ is a distribution describing how the density of states of a quasiparticle with energy E is modelled, so how can the distribution of electrons in general relate to that of quasiparticles in the superconducting state?